# How to make gitpython ask for authentication credentials every time?

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

I use gitpython for cloning, pulling, committing, and pushing repo.
While cloning, it asks for a username, and password and stored inside .git/configs.

So every time, a user makes a commit and push it simply done without authentication.
My VM is deployed in AWS and used by any team member. I want that it should ask for username and password, every time a user makes a clone, commit, pull and push request, and it shouldn't store the password locally.

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to pass `-c credential.helper=` to the commands, like `git -c credential.helper= clone`. See